# Project Euler 233

Tags: c#

> Let f(N) be the number of points with integer coordinates that are on
>   a circle passing through (0,0), (N,0), (0,N), and (N,N).
>
> It can be shown that f(10000) = 36.
>
> What is the sum of all positive integers N  1011 such that
>   f(N) = 420 ?

Alright, so I think that I have the basic idea for Project Euler number 233. Here is my code:

```
/*
 * Andrew Koroluk
 */

public class euler233 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(f(10000));
    System.out.println(f(1328125));
    System.out.println(f(84246500));
    System.out.println(f(248431625));
    //if(true) return;

    double ans = 0;
    for(double N=10000; N<=(Math.pow(10, 11)); N++) {
        //System.out.println(N);
        if( f(N)==420 ) {
            ans+= N;
            System.out.println(N);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
}
static double f(double N) {
    double ans = 0;     
    double r = Math.sqrt(2*N*N)/2;
    //System.out.println(r*r);
    double r2 = r*r;

    for(int x=1; x<=r; x++) {
        for(int y=1; y<=r; y++) {
            if( x*x + y*y == r2 ) {
                ans+=4;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
static boolean isInt(double a) {
    if(a==(int)a) return true;
    return false;
}
}
```

Basically what I am doing is finding solutions for right triangles inscribed inside the circle, having a hypotenuse the length of the circles diameter. I am not positive that my code is correct.

If it is correct, then my problem is optimizing the f(N) function and optimizing the loop to find numbers for f(N) = 420.

New Code:

```
public class euler233 {
    static long[] primes;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(r(1328125));
        Clock c = new Clock();
        System.out.println(f2(10000));
        c.getTimeSeconds();
        c.reset();

        System.out.println(f2(1328125));
        c.getTimeSeconds();
    }
    static long f2(long N) {
        return SquaresR2(N*N);
    }
    static boolean isInt(long a) {
        if(a==(int)a) return true;
        return false;
    }
    static int SquaresR2(long n) {
        //System.out.println("start");
        int sum = 0;
        outer:
        for(int a=0; a<Math.sqrt(n)-1; a++) {
            for(int b=0; b<Math.sqrt(n)-1; b++) {
                if( a*a + b*b == n ) {
                    if(a>b) break outer;
                    sum+=4;
                    System.out.println(n+" = "+a+"^2 + "+b+"^2");
                }
            }
        }
        sum*=2;

        if(Math.sqrt(n)==(int)Math.sqrt(n)) sum+=4;
        return sum;
    }
    static int r(int n) {
        return 4*(d1(n) - d3(n));
    }
    private static int d1(int n) {
        int k=1, sum=0;
        while(true) {
            int d = 4*k+1;
            if(d>n) break;
            if(n%d==0) sum++;
            k++;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    private static int d3(int n) {
        int k=1, sum=0;
        while(true) {
            int d = 4*k+3;
            if(d>n) break;
            if(n%d==0) sum++;
            k++;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Is my approach correct?
2. How can I optimize the code to run quickly?

Comment: Why dont you define the problem as a courtesy to those who don't want to look it up.

Comment: -1 and vote to close. The rules of project-euler discourage using foreign help. From the bottom of the problems page: `If you can't solve it, then you can't solve it!` http://projecteuler.net/problems

Comment: There was no need for a downvote. I am not asking for the solution. I am just asking for hints to point me in the right direction. Project Euler has no problem with people giving other people hints. You do not know what you are talking about and should not have given a downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few points:

1. **Don't use floating point numbers for this.**
2. Apart from that, your algorithm is in principle correct.
3. But it won't finish before the heat death of the universe.

You have to find a much better approach, a few hints:

1. Use only integer maths.
2. Have a look at an introduction to number theory. Squares and right triangles might be interesting. Oh, and primes.
3. Have fun.
4. Let me repeat, number theory (but very basic, you can understand the relevant bits with high school math background; you will have to invest a bit of time though).

Comment: -1 The idea of project-euler is to find the solution yourself. From the bottom of the problems page: If you can't solve it, then you can't solve it! See http://projecteuler.net/problems .

Comment: Thanks for explaining the downvote, I appreciate that. I know the idea of doing it yourself quite well, but the general advice given here is well within limits, you can get much more concrete hints for numerous problems at the [forum](http://forum.projecteuler.net) - or at least one could when I was still involved.

Comment: In the forum, you can discuss your solution, **after** solving the problem.

Comment: I meant the companion site, take a look at [this topic](http://forum.projecteuler.net/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=949), some near-spoilers there.

Comment: There was no need for a downvote. Project Euler has no problem with people giving other people hints. You do not know what you are talking about and should not have given a downvote.

Comment: My impression is, that the spoilers are on my side.

Comment: @userunknown which spoilers are on your side? Just to be clear, I find your position with respect to hints way exaggerated, but not fundamentally wrong. Hints should be not too explicit. But nudging people carefully in the right direction was very much part of the game, we all participated in that. I maintain that my hints (don't do it that way, learn some elementary number theory instead) were adequate, and part of the reason for my answer was to discourage more explicit guidance. You have the right to disagree, of course. Reasonable people can draw the line at different points.

Comment: @DanielFischer I completely agree with you. I have tried to re-visualize my code using only longs to jump right to r^2. I am now trying to see how primes could play in with this. As I am only a high school student and only know some basics of number theory I expect this to riddle my brain for quite some time. Thank you.

Comment: High school? Then you'll probably need some more guidance. There are a few earlier problems touching the relevant theory. Reviewing them and pursuing what seem to be promising topics might help. One of the earlier problems contains a highly relevant component.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you know which specific problems would help me? I have 91 done so far.

Comment: Okay, so I think what I need to do is find the Sum of Squares r(2,N^2) for each number. Two problems: My sum of squares function takes forever to run (.6 seconds for 10000), and I am not sure what kinds of numbers would get me 420 (I dont think you would have to test for ALL numbers under 10^11). I also tried making a method for Schinzel's Theorem, but I get 60 for 10000; I have posted the new code I tried in my original post.